# How to have websites fit the screen?

Tags: resolution, browser

on high resolution screens websites are mostly blank.How to have them stretched to fit the screen?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfpKE.png]

I've tried Internet Explorer and Opera and on Linux too: Firefox and Chrome

Comment: have you tried other browsers?

Comment: What browser do you use

Comment: @user320473 see my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/516038/158442) for Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Maybe some script? (maybe Greasemonkey like scripts)

Answer (score 2):

The default zoom in Firefox can be reset to any value for all webpages without installing an extension.

1. In the Firefox address bar type: `about:config`
2. Search for this preference: `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`
3. Replace the default value of `-1.0` with the new percentage zoom. For example, if you want to change the default zoom from the default value of 100% to 125%, then change the value of `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` to `1.25`

If you are also using Chrome web browser then the default zoom level can be easily changed from the settings ( 3 vertical dots icon  **⋮** ) in the upper right corner of Chrome. For a better browsing experience set the same default zoom for both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: This was tested on the latest version of Firefox 57 (a.k.a. Firefox Quantum) and Chrome 62.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious from your screenshot which browser you use, but in Chrome I zoom in to about 175% to have things "fit to size".

How far you need to zoom is dependent on your resolution, size of the monitor, the website itself, etc.:

- If you use Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/font-size-and-zoom-increase-size-of-web-pages
- If you use Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=en

Here's what mine looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can press ctrl and the plus minus keys to zoom in and out, this is remembered per page in fire fox but in chrome you can set a default in settings. (175% for 1080p)

Answer (score 0):

This will have to be done per browser.

For Firefox, you can use addons like [Default FullZoom Level](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/default-fullzoom-level/), so that websites automatically open at a higher zoom:
[image]

For Google Chrome/Chromium, you can set the default zoom without any extensions. Go to the Settings, search for *Page zoom*, and change the value in the *Web content* section:
[image: Google Chrome screenshot].

I too keep a 175% zoom for Ask Ubuntu, but I start out 125-150% as a default for new sites.

Comment: Default Zoom Level does nothing

Comment: @user320473 which version of Firefox? The add on works fine for me.

Comment: version http://pastebin.com/2DKWNm3P