# Smaller Font and web pages not fit to screen resolution

Tags: resolution

I have Lenovo Ideapad Y510p device. I have just installed ubuntu 14.04. After installing ubuntu the login screen and other fonts are apprearing smaller. Also it is very annoying that the web pages are not fit to screen resolution. It has both Intel and Nvidia drivers.

Tried a lot by installing nvidia latest driver but no results.

Please assist if anyone have any way.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your system font, go to System Settings and check Displays. There is an option called 'Scale for menu and title bars:'. Change the value on the scale given below that to change font size. Regarding websites, I guess it changes based on the browser you use and the website you visit. Check this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516033/how-to-have-websites-fit-the-screen). Hopefully it will solve your problem.