# Flashgot problem

Tags: 16.04, firefox, plugins, firefox-extensions, uget

I got Firefox Quantum and also I have uGet but I can't download because I don't have flashGot(I can't add to Firefox because it says that is not compatible with Firefox Quantum). Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: If FlashGot is important to you, [installing Firefox ESR](https://askubuntu.com/a/977140) is one option, even if it's just a temporary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, FlashGot is no longer supported by its developer.
I too faced such a problem before, but I found no way to make FlashGot work again.
The best alternative I have so far is using Xtreme Download Manager (XDM) as my Flash downloader. It works very well, and IMO it's better than FlashGot.

Every time there is downloadable content, XDM will show a "download video" dialog box in the bottom right (check my screenshot).

[image]

XDM makes your download 5 times faster, just like IDM does. 
It's by far the best IDM alternative for Linux, at least for me.
You should try it.

[Download link](http://xdman.sourceforge.net)

Comment: how do you exactly integrate XDM? With what browser? Is it Chromium/Chrome? With what extensions?

Comment: unfortunately, it's addon is not compatible with Firefox 58

Comment: It's addon is compatible with both chrome and firefox quantum. You need to download the latest version from their website (the link I share above). Never download via terminal. The version served there is outdated (it is XDM 2016). You should download XDM 2018 from their official website.

Answer (score 1):

Get Firefox ESR which still has support for "old" addons

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/firefox-esr
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```