# Embedded facebook videos in firefox 60

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I'm relatively new to Linux, using Ubuntu 16.04 running Firefox 60 browser. My browser just updated to 60 last night, having previously been version 47 that came with the distro. During the update, firefox disabled nearly every plugin that was installed on 47. In neither version of firefox can I get embedded videos to play. Youtube videos seem to play just fine. In looking thru the forum, I've only run across partial answers. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have had many LEGACY addons (not plugins) - you can "downgrade" Firefox to 52.8.1 ESR (it's supported and have all security updates) - see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/977140/66509). The Flash Player has recently upgraded to 30.0.0.113 and it works in both ESR and Quantum (you can check your FlashPlayer version on [this page](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/)) - so you should have video.

Comment: Do i need to remove the current version of firefox first, or will the retrograde installation overwrite the current one?

Comment: Firefox from JonathonF PPA (`ppa:jonathonf/firefox-esr`) will remove your current version and will use its profile from your home folder.