# firefox in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox

installed firefox 54 on ubuntu 16.04. The last command was `sudo ln -s /opt/firefox55/firefox-bin /usr/bin/firefox`. When I want to run firefox using `firefox`, it says permission denied. What is the problem? Would the old firefox version works with something like`firefoxold`?

Comment: Could run these to collect some info and add output to the question? `which firefox; ls -l /usr/bin/firefox; ls -l /opt/firefox55/firefox-bin`

Comment: Once agin i extracted tar package & ran  "sudo ln -s /opt/firefox54/firefox-bin /usr/bin/firefox". when i run "firefox", it says "cannot execute binary file:Exec format error".                                  which firefox gives: usr/bin/firefox.                   ls -l /usr/bin/firefox: lrwxrwxrwx root root /usr/bin/firefox->/opt/firefox54/firefox-bin.                                                                                                                        ls -l /opt/firefox54/firefox-bin gives -rwxr-xr-x crnd crnd /opt/firefox54/firefox-bin

Comment: This is not answering your question, but one thing to consider is to use firefox snap. `sudo snap install firefox` Much easier

Comment: You may be interested in installation of ESR version (you will get security updates and it supports legacy addons). See this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/977140/66509).

Answer (score 0):

The mistake i did was that i unzipped the tar package in windows machine and then copied the unzipped folder to ubuntu system. I should extract the tar package in ubuntu only. This was my first mistake. 
And regarding  "cannot execute binary file:Exec format error", this was bcause i installed 64bit package of mozilla whereas it is 32-bit OS. THese two things i changed  and as of now it works...Incase it helps someone so posting